# How do i make a nested div translucent to show body tag's background image?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a div thats inside the container div. Now i want to make the inner-most-divs translucent to show the bodies background image. Or can this be done?

To make my question clearer, i used a green border for the div i want to target. I want this div to be slightly translucent so that the body tag's background is visible only in this div. Im thinking z-index should be used here but im not sure how

```
 .forum-column{
border: 2px solid green;
/*background-image: url(http://kenstonlocal.org/kenston/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/css_code.jpg);
background-size: cover;*/
background-color: rgb(35,35,35);
overflow: hidden;
height: 50px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
```

}

https://jsfiddle.net/jmann1622/hgm0gzs0/2/

I'm aware of opacity and rgba. But my problem is that my target(green border) is inside another div(orange border) which itself is inside another div(red border). Now i do not want any of the other divs to be transparent, only the green bordered div.And i want this (green bordered div) to be translucent so that the body tag's sky image can be seen. Sorry for the confusion, noob here

Comment: This has nothing to do with JS nor jQuery. Please tag questions properly in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**option-1**: Use css property `opacity:[0-1]`

```
.forum-column{
   border: 2px solid green;
   /*background-image: url(http://kenstonlocal.org/kenston/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/css_code.jpg);
   background-size: cover;*/
   background-color: rgb(35,35,35);
   overflow: hidden;
   opacity:0.4;
   height: 50px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

**option-2**: Use `rgba(red,green,blue,alpha)` for background-color where alpha is from 0-1 and specifies the translucency

```
.forum-column{
   border: 2px solid green;
   /*background-image: url(http://kenstonlocal.org/kenston/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/css_code.jpg);
   background-size: cover;*/
   background-color: rgba(35,35,35,0.4);
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 50px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rgba for most browsers..
rgba(35,35,35,.8)  the last part is a number from 0-1 to indicate transparency level..

Answer (score 0):

Just use rgba for background color.

```
.innerDiv {
  background-color: rgba(35, 35, 35, .5);
}
```

The last value for a (alpha) can be between 0(100% transparent) to 1(100% opaque).

This will make the innermost div tranparent and the background divs will remain visible through it.

Hope it helps.